# Pandas DataFrame Dividing a column by itself taking first element and divide all the rows and so on

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame from Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"a":[1.,3.,5.,2.]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

df1:

```
    a
0   1.0
1   3.0
2   5.0
3   2.0
```

Now I want to iterate over the rows. For every row, divided by the first elements of the same column and then iterate elements.

Taking all the rows one by one and divided by the first element as standard in the denominator and all rows with second elements and so on.

For example:
1./1., 3./1., 5./1., 2./1. and take next element 1./3., 3./3., 5./3., 2./3. and next, 1./5.,3./5.,5./5.,2./5.  and then last 1./2., 3./2., 5./2., 2./2.

and python code works well with for loop.

```
def div(x):

    d = []

    for i in range(len(x)):

        for j in range(len(x)):

            di = x.iloc[j,:]/x.iloc[i,:]

            d.append(di)

    return d


div(df1)
```

If I have huge dataset like 15000 rows and I want to implement using `applymap()` or `map()`

```
result = df.applymap(div)
```

or

```
result = map(div,df1)

print(list(result))
```

It gives an error for both.
Maybe if anyone could help me to optimize my code would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to increase the speed of the process:

```
>>> df1
     a
   a_1
   a_2
0  1.0
1  3.0
2  5.0
3  2.0
```

```
import numpy as np

a = np.hstack(df1.values)
m = np.repeat(a, len(a)).reshape((a.shape[0], -1))

df = pd.DataFrame(a / m, columns=df1.columns.repeat(len(df1)))
```

```
>>> df
          a
        a_1
        a_2  a_2       a_2       a_2
0  1.000000  3.0  5.000000  2.000000
1  0.333333  1.0  1.666667  0.666667
2  0.200000  0.6  1.000000  0.400000
3  0.500000  1.5  2.500000  1.000000

>>> a
array([1., 3., 5., 2.])

>>> m
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.]])
```

Used function and method:

- [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)
- [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: Thanks Corralien. It helps me with dataframe column having single header. What if DataFrame df1 have 3 header a ,a_1 and a_2 in the same column and followed by values [1.,3.,5.,2.].

Comment: Can you show me an example because I don't get it?

Comment: For example: 
>>> df1
     a
     a_1
     a_2
0  1.0
1  3.0
2  5.0
3  2.0

Dataframe have multiple headers. How can i go with this data with your code ?

Comment: Multiple headers but one column, is right? You have a multiindex? What is the output of `df.columns`

Comment: Yes correct (Multiple headers but one column) and output should remain the same as you got in your post.

Comment: @Jackish. I updated my answer to take account multiindex dataframe.

Comment: sorry i am not used to it. I accepted it now. Thanks @Corralien

Answer (score 1):

We can use numpy division by dividing the Series [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) and the DataFrame [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
results = pd.DataFrame(df1['a'].to_numpy() / df1.to_numpy())
```

`results`:

```
          0    1         2         3
0  1.000000  3.0  5.000000  2.000000
1  0.333333  1.0  1.666667  0.666667
2  0.200000  0.6  1.000000  0.400000
3  0.500000  1.5  2.500000  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, It helps me with dataframe column having single header. What if DataFrame df1 have 3 header a ,a_1 and a_2 in the same column and followed by values [1.,3.,5.,2.].